# largest array, sorted in reverse order from the given array

Tags: python, list, sorting

What is the largest array, sorted in reverse order from the given array?

```
Input: [25,28,11,10,9, 8,17, 23,20,19,14] 

Output:[[28,11,10,9,8],[23,20,19,14]]
```

I tried google but didnt found any solution Please help me to resolved this issue. here is the code that I am trying to write, but didn't clear to much.

```
 def findRuns(L):
    result = []
    start = 0
    n = L[start]
    for i,num in enumerate(L):
        if num <= n:
            n = num
        else:
            answer.append(L[start:1])
            start = i
            n = L[i]
    result.append(L[start])
    return result
```

Please help me to resolved this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So you're trying to do it in Python, Ruby or C?

Comment: The output for the second input seems incorrect. Is that the output of your code, or the expected output?

Comment: any programing , but prefer python bcs i am using python to resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def findRuns(L):
    answer = []
    start = 0
    n = L[start]
    for i,num in enumerate(L[1:],1):
        if num <= n:
            n = num
        else:
            answer.append(L[start:i])
            start = i
            n = L[start]
    answer.append(L[start:])
    return answer
```

Output:

```
In [48]: findRuns([25,28,11,10,9, 8, 23] )
Out[48]: [[25], [28, 11, 10, 9, 8], [23]]

In [49]: findRuns([25,28,11,10,9, 8,17, 23,20,19,14] )
Out[49]: [[25], [28, 11, 10, 9, 8], [17], [23, 20, 19, 14]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a grouper function and then find the biggest group based on length using `max()`:

```
def grouper(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    grp = [next(it)]
    for item in it:
        if item <= grp[-1]:
            grp.append(item)
        else:
            yield grp
            grp = [item]
    if grp:
        yield grp

inp1 = [25,28,11,10,9, 8, 23] 
inp2 = [25,28,11,10,9, 8,17, 23,20,19,14] 

print max(grouper(inp1), key=len)
#[28, 11, 10, 9, 8]
print max(grouper(inp2), key=len)
#[28, 11, 10, 9, 8]
print list(grouper(inp2))
#[[25], [28, 11, 10, 9, 8], [17], [23, 20, 19, 14]]
```